# PHP and Mysql, how can I group students (3 students per group) using their CPGA scores? each group must have high, medium $ low cgpa students

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table containing 40 students with their CGPA, I want the system to place 3 students into one group, the system should decide which students to combine (students with high, medium and lower CGPA) finally I want to insert the id of each students in a group to a new Mysql table, how can I achieve this using PHP

Comment: What will you do with the single remaining student?

Comment: the remaining single student will be added to one of the groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM students
ORDER BY cgpa DESC;
```

Assuming you have this query result as `$students` array you can do:

```
$grouped = [];
$group_count = intdiv(count($students), 3); //calculating number of groups
for($i=0;$i<$group_count;$i++){
   //loop group number times  
   $arr = []; // empty array
   $counter = $i;
   for($j=0;$j<3;$j++){
       //loop student number times in group
       array_push($arr, $students[$counter]);//add 3 student that has high, medium and low cgpa to array to create 1 group
       $counter+=$group_count;
   }
   array_push($grouped, $arr);// add created student group to new array
}
```

`$grouped` is array of students

Comment: Yes, this will work, but you still need to take into account that the student count divided by 3 does not return a whole number. You can use `$group_count = intdiv(count($students), 3);` and then handle any remaining students. An explanation of the code would also be a nice addition.

Comment: thank you for answering my question. And yes I would love a little explanation too if possible. I want the new array to store the 'id' of those students in the group and insert the id to new Mysql table called 'groups'.

Comment: @Biruk Kassaye check edited answer. Is it helpful for you?

Comment: @Vüsal Hüseynli thanks again, and it would be a lot helpful if you could provide me a way in inserting this data to new table.

Comment: I am sorry but this is exact different question. I don't know what table you gonna create, how many columns you want to have or are you gonna use related tables and so on. Feel free to ask new question about inserting data to mysql table, so we can help you out there.

Comment: okay thank you, but to clarify more, what should be on the '$students' array and what is stored on the '$arr' array?

Comment: I have added some edits to the question

Comment: @BirukKassaye If you want to insert the results of a query into another table, use an INSERT...SELECT style query. There are examples and documentation available online.

Comment: @ADyson it's not clear where the group data is stored on the above code example...  which array contains the students details?

Comment: @BirukKassaye if you follow my suggestion it wouldn't matter, because the whole operation would be done within the SQL, PHP would not be needed to process the data

Comment: @BirukKassaye if the example isn't clear, why not run the code and var_dump the arrays at the end, so you can see what they contain? Then you might see more easily if it does anything useful for you.

Comment: @ADyson I already tried var_dump yet it is not displaying anything useful

Comment: @BirukKassaye You did `var_dump$grouped);` and `var_dump($students);` at the end? By "useful" you mean you saw some output but it wasn't what you wanted? Or you saw nothing at all? If you want to give the OP of this answer feedback on their code then you need to be a lot more specific about what the problem is.

Comment: @ADyson I tried var_dump($grouped) and it gave 'array (size=0)
  empty'

Comment: @BirukKassaye make sure your query result comes as an array.

Comment: how can I get my query result as an array... I simply used 'mysqli_query($con, $sql);' on the $result variable

Comment: @BirukKassaye you can read that in any number of tutorials and examples online. [Start here](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysqli+result+to+array)

Comment: Glad to help you)